# How do I show that if T*T = Id$_{V}$ then TT* = Id$_{V}$, where T is a linear transformation and T* is its adjoint operator?

Tags: linear-algebra

We can use that (T*)*=T because I have shown that while trying to work on this one. I am just plane stuck on this one. V is also finite dimensional

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space and $T$ is a linear operator on $V$, then $T^*T=I$ implies that $\ker(T)=\{0\}$, hence $T$ is invertible.  Multiplying the identity $T^*T=I$ on the right by $T^{-1}$ shows that $T^*=T^{-1}$, hence also $TT^*=I$.

If $V$ is not finite-dimensional then the result is not true in general. Consider for instance $V=\ell^2(\mathbb{N})$, and let $T$ be the map
$$ (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)\mapsto (0,x_1,x_2,\dots) $$
Then $T^*$ is the map
$$ (x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)\mapsto (x_2,x_3,x_4,\dots) $$
and $T^*T=I$, but $TT^*\neq I$.

Comment: Yeah I was talking about finite dimensional V, I will edit that.

Comment: Thank you so much @carmichael561.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.